# Effective while loop condition for client choices (TCP connection in linux - C)

Tags: c, networking, tcp, file-transfer

I am trying to make a TCP  file transferconnection that enables the client to choose what "task" he wants to do (list files in directory, upload, download a file), but not terminate once he makes a choice.  Meaning he can do more than one choice per session.

The problem I have is that in my implementation of the while loop on the server side:

```
while(n= read(sd,rbuf,BUFLEN)){


    if (rbuf[0] == 'R'){//CHANGE DIR
        //char *dircha;

        //read(sd, rbuf, BUFLEN);


        printf("ENTER change directory\n");
        //chdir(dircha);// this will change directory
    }

    if(rbuf[0] == 'L'){//LIST FILES

        requiem[0] = 'I';
        requiem[1] =  20;
        printf("TYPE: %c", requiem[0]);
        write(sd, requiem , 2);.... //rest of code
```

The rbuf doesnt get "cleared" and still contains the characters the client made when he typed his choices,  and once it enters the while loop and picks a choice, it will never be able to choose another task because rbuf[0] will never be equal to any of the choices i made.

What can I do to make it so that the user can make multiple choices?  Thank you so much!

Comment: `while(n= read(sd,rbuf,BUFLEN)){` n might be negative. take care.

Comment: Using [select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)) can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(n= read(sd,rbuf,BUFLEN)){
```

is not a good way for implementing your protocol. There is no guarantee that it returns exactly one dataset. E.g. it is possible that:

- the `read()` returns data from two or more `write()`, or that
- the `read()` returns only partial data from a `write()`

You should implement either some buffering or a better encoding of your data (e.g. prefix always the type or the length of following data).

Comment: Yeah, for the millionth time,,